# How to forcefully hook the events between C sharp exe and VC++ embedded dll on it?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-c++, mfc

I have a C# application having various input controls(TextBox, ComboBox, Buttons etc.) along with a tab control. In one of the tabs I have an unmanaged C++ window embedded in it. The C++ windows has few input controls too.

Using tab key, I am able to navigate to C# controls witohut any issues. However when I select a control on the C++ window and press tab, it does not transfer the focus to the next control on the C++ window. Rather, it sets the focus to a control on a C# control.

As per other posts, if we have an embedded unmanaged form, at a managed level (C# application), the .NET control will be unaware it has any children.

How to forcefully hook the events between C sharp exe and VC++ embedded dll on it?

Comment: Yes, but title is different :P

Comment: Ayush, if the title on your original question was wrong, you can edit it. Please don't just ask the same question again just because you didn't get any answers to your first question. This makes it difficult for other users of the site to find information. If you want more attention, you can [offer a bounty instead](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty), it will cost you a minimum of 50 rep.

Comment: I didnt know about this bounty concept.Thanks Rowland